# Gnuplot - show palette palette and set print - do not print the message "Color palette with x discrete colors saved to

Tags: gnuplot

I am generating gnuplot scripts with Python. Some of the Gnuplot scripts create graphs (with only a few points on them) with a color variation. I have to reuse the same colors for other graphs. I have discovered that it is possible to use the command

```
show palette palette <n>
```

to get the RGB values corresponding to the colors used by a graph with a color variation. I have therefore decided to save the values in a file (that is read later when the colors have to be loaded) thanks to the command:

```
set print file.txt
```

Everything work really fine, but I am getting a printing problem: each time the script saves the color values in a file, it prints the message:

```
"Color palette with <x> discrete colors saved to <file.txt>"
```

I would prefer not to print this message, because my main script executes many such gnuplot scripts, and all these unimportant messages on the screen make it complicated to see the other (more important) messages.

Would anyone know how to prevent gnuplot from printing this message?

(I have already tried to change the standard output: all the normal prints (the ones the rest of the code does) are not visible anymore, but the gnuplot prints still appear).

Thank you in advance for your help,

Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Unix system you can start gnuplot with

```
gnuplot 2>/dev/null
```

which dumps all messages that are sent to `stderr`, like the color message, to `/dev/null` and hence removes them from the screen.

But that removes also all error messages. You cannot selectively remove only the color message.